# Parse HTML regex problema

Tags: php, regex, parser

Bom a duvida que tenho é a seguinte, preciso pegar o seguinte trecho do HTML logo abaixo:

HTML:

```
        <section class="ovw-summary">

                <div class="ovw-summary__balance balance-amounts">
                    <header><h3>Meu dinheiro</h3></header>
                    <div class="box-container mp-box-shadow bg-trama">

                        <dl class="balance-amounts__list available-money">
                            <dt>Disponível</dt>
                            <dd class="price price-large mlb">
                            <span class="price-symbol">R$</span> <span class="price-integer">0</span><span class="price-decimal-mark">,</span><span class="price-decimal">00</span>
                            </dd>
                        </dl>
                        <dl class="balance-amounts__list account-money">
                            <dt>Em conta</dt>
                            <dd class="price">
                            <span class="price-symbol">R$</span> <span class="price-integer">24</span><span class="price-decimal-mark">,</span><span class="price-decimal">99</span> 
                            </dd>
                        </dl>
```

Eu fiz dessa forma pra pode ler o HTML e me retorna os dados correto. Aqui meu código em PHP fiz uma regex vejam como está:

```
$SaldoEmConta = '~<dl class="account-money">\s*<dt>Em conta<\/dt>\s*<dd class="ch-price" name="balance_total" value=".*?">R\$ (.*?)<sup>(.*?)<\/sup>\s*<a href=".*?" class="icon-info-balance">\s*<i class="ch-icon-help-sign">\s*<\/i>\s*<\/a>\s*<\/dd>\s*<\/dl>~';
preg_match($SaldoEmConta, $RetornoSaldo, $ArrayConta);

$SaldoDisponivel = '~<dl class="open-detail">\s*<dt class="available-label">Dispon&iacute;vel<\/dt>\s*<dd class="ch-price available-price" name="balance_available" value=".*">R\$ (.*?)<sup>(.*?)<\/sup>\s*<\/dd>~';
preg_match($SaldoEmConta, $RetornoSaldo, $ArrayDisponivel);

echo 'Em conta: R$ ' . $ArrayConta[1].','.$ArrayConta[2]  . ' Disponivel: R$ ' . $ArrayDisponivel[1].','.$ArrayDisponivel[2] .'<hr>';
```

Mas por algum motivo não consigo pega esses valores alguém pode me ajuda a corrigir a minha expressão regular?

Comment: Estás a abrir HTML no lado do servidor e queres mudar esse HTML para enviar para o lado do cliente, é isso? Podes explicar melhor o que queres fazer e de onde vêm esse HTML?

Comment: Depois de acessar por cURL preciso pega esses valores no html que retorna .

Comment: Trabalhar HTML em PHP via RegExp é pouco fiável... não dá para ir buscar esses dados noutro formato tipo JSON?

Comment: Não da , antes deles atualizar o layout do site onde acesso pra busca o valor  tava me retornando normalmente os dados.

Answer (score 1):

Não utilize Regex, utilize um parser de HTML como o simpleparser:

http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

ou o ganon:

http://code.google.com/p/ganon/

Os 2 são bem mais tranquilos de trabalhar com HTML.

Um exemplo com o simpleparser:

```
$html = str_get_html('<div id="hello">Hello</div><div id="world">World</div>');
$html->find('div', 1)->class = 'bar';
$html->find('div[id=hello]', 0)->innertext = 'foo';
echo $html; // Output: <div id="hello">foo</div><div id="world" class="bar">World</div>
```

Só pra complementar, é sempre uma boa leitura: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Answer (score 0):

Pode usar esta expressão regular, acho que casa com o que voce precisa:

```
balance_unavailable['"]\s+value=['"](\d*\.?\d*).*balance_dispute['"]\s+value=['"](\d*\.?\d*)
```

Comment: aqui deu erro Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ']'